# Find the number of employees in each department - SQL Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I have two tables `Emp` and `Dept` and I am trying to display how many people work in each department along with their department name, but I can't get it to work. I have tried this `select count(ename) as count from emp group by deptno;` but the output I am getting is this :

```
 COUNT
----------
     6
     5
     3
```

But I also want to show the names for each of those departments. Here are my tables :

Empt:

```
CREATE TABLE EMP
       (EMPNO NUMBER(4) NOT NULL,
        ENAME VARCHAR2(10),
        JOB VARCHAR2(9),
        MGR NUMBER(4),
        HIREDATE DATE,
        SAL NUMBER(7, 2),
        COMM NUMBER(7, 2),
        DEPTNO NUMBER(2));

INSERT INTO EMP VALUES
        (7369, 'SMITH',  'CLERK',     7902,
        TO_DATE('17-DEC-1980', 'DD-MON-YYYY'),  800, NULL, 20);
INSERT INTO EMP VALUES
        (7499, 'ALLEN',  'SALESMAN',  7698,
        TO_DATE('20-FEB-1981', 'DD-MON-YYYY'), 1600,  300, 30);
INSERT INTO EMP VALUES
        (7521, 'WARD',   'SALESMAN',  7698,
        TO_DATE('22-FEB-1981', 'DD-MON-YYYY'), 1250,  500, 30);
INSERT INTO EMP VALUES
        (7566, 'JONES',  'MANAGER',   7839,
        TO_DATE('2-APR-1981', 'DD-MON-YYYY'),  2975, NULL, 20);
INSERT INTO EMP VALUES
        (7654, 'MARTIN', 'SALESMAN',  7698,
        TO_DATE('28-SEP-1981', 'DD-MON-YYYY'), 1250, 1400, 30);
INSERT INTO EMP VALUES
        (7698, 'BLAKE',  'MANAGER',   7839,
        TO_DATE('1-MAY-1981', 'DD-MON-YYYY'),  2850, NULL, 30);
INSERT INTO EMP VALUES
        (7782, 'CLARK',  'MANAGER',   7839,
        TO_DATE('9-JUN-1981', 'DD-MON-YYYY'),  2450, NULL, 10);
INSERT INTO EMP VALUES
        (7788, 'SCOTT',  'ANALYST',   7566,
        TO_DATE('09-DEC-1982', 'DD-MON-YYYY'), 3000, NULL, 20);
INSERT INTO EMP VALUES
        (7839, 'KING',   'PRESIDENT', NULL,
        TO_DATE('17-NOV-1981', 'DD-MON-YYYY'), 5000, NULL, 10);
INSERT INTO EMP VALUES
        (7844, 'TURNER', 'SALESMAN',  7698,
        TO_DATE('8-SEP-1981', 'DD-MON-YYYY'),  1500,    0, 30);
INSERT INTO EMP VALUES
        (7876, 'ADAMS',  'CLERK',     7788,
        TO_DATE('12-JAN-1983', 'DD-MON-YYYY'), 1100, NULL, 20);
INSERT INTO EMP VALUES
        (7900, 'JAMES',  'CLERK',     7698,
        TO_DATE('3-DEC-1981', 'DD-MON-YYYY'),   950, NULL, 30);
INSERT INTO EMP VALUES
        (7902, 'FORD',   'ANALYST',   7566,
        TO_DATE('3-DEC-1981', 'DD-MON-YYYY'),  3000, NULL, 20);
INSERT INTO EMP VALUES
        (7934, 'MILLER', 'CLERK',     7782,
        TO_DATE('23-JAN-1982', 'DD-MON-YYYY'), 1300, NULL, 10);
```

Dept:

```
CREATE TABLE DEPT
       (DEPTNO NUMBER(2),
        DNAME VARCHAR2(14),
        LOC VARCHAR2(13) );

INSERT INTO DEPT VALUES (10, 'ACCOUNTING', 'NEW YORK');
INSERT INTO DEPT VALUES (20, 'RESEARCH',   'DALLAS');
INSERT INTO DEPT VALUES (30, 'SALES',      'CHICAGO');
INSERT INTO DEPT VALUES (40, 'OPERATIONS', 'BOSTON');
```

Comment: Hint:  `JOIN`.  `GROUP BY`.

Comment: Do you have tried any query? If yes, please post it here.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Please try:

```
select count(*) as count,dept.DNAME 
from emp 
inner join dept on emp.DEPTNO = dept.DEPTNO 
group by dept.DNAME
```

Comment: This is correct only if department names are unique (no duplicates), which is not specified in the question.

Comment: Yes, in his example data they are unique that's why I removed DEPTNO.

Comment: Count(*) will count the null values

Answer (score 7):

A request to list "Number of employees in each department" or "Display how many people work in each department" is the same as "For each department, list the number of employees", this must include departments with no employees.  In the sample database, Operations has 0 employees. So a LEFT OUTER JOIN should be used.

```
SELECT dept.name, COUNT(emp.empno) AS count
FROM dept
LEFT OUTER JOIN emp ON emp.deptno = dept.deptno
GROUP BY dept.name;
```

Answer (score 2):

```
select count(e.empno), d.deptno, d.dname 
from emp e, dep d
where e.DEPTNO = d.DEPTNO 
group by d.deptno, d.dname;
```

Answer (score 2):

Try the query below:

```
select count(*),d.dname from emp e , dept d where d.deptno = e.deptno
group by d.dname
```

Comment: try to explain your answer

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT d.DEPTNO
    , d.dname
    , COUNT(e.ename) AS count
FROM   emp e
      INNER JOIN dept d ON e.DEPTNO = d.deptno
GROUP BY d.deptno
      , d.dname;
```

Answer (score 1):

**Try to do this:**

```
SQL> select dept,count(*) "no of emp" from employee group by dept;

DEPT                  no of emp
-------------------- ----------
HR                            2
Account                       2
Admin                         3
```

Answer (score 0):

```sql
select  d.dname
       ,count(e.empno) as count 
from dept d 
left outer join emp e 
  on e.deptno=d.deptno 
group by d.dname;
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

select count(EMPNO),DNAME from EMP e join DEPT d on e.DEPTNO = d.DEPTNO group by DNAME ;